# create a background Hosted service that can obtain current logged in user info then preform certain scheduled tasks

Tags: asp.net-core

I have built a web application via asp.net core, and now I am planning to implement a background service such as IHostedService, BackgroundService etc..

My application does require to only run the worker service if they user is being logged in, so if user being logged in I need the background service to obtain user info, then preform certain scheduled tasks, thus if user close application or logged out the background service must stop preforming the tasks for that specific user.

How can I make a background service run only if user is logged in

Comment: There is no question here. What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: the issue is services are started immediately once web application being started. i want the service to only start if user is logged in then the services start scheduled task for that user. how to do so ?

Comment: I would have one service that is always running and just checks who has logged in recently to perform tasks for those users. You would need some way of tracking who has logged in on the server side.